# How to get similarly formatted yaml for "safe" and "round-trip"

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

`ruamel.yaml` formats a simple, but nested dictionary differently depending on if it's using the `safe` or the `round-trip` representer.

I can't see why the different repersenters should format such a simple dictionary differently, so I'm wondering how to get the `safe` representer to look similar to the `round-trip` one in the following example:

```py
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

data = {'data': {'interval': 5, 'compression': '3'}, 'player': {'ffmpeg': {'name': 'me'}}}
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This prints

```
data: {compression: '3', interval: 5}
player:
  ffmpeg: {name: me}
```

But

```py
yaml = YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

prints a much nicer output:

```
data:
  interval: 5
  compression: '3'
player:
  ffmpeg:
    name: me
```

How can I get the `safe` version to print similarity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of the`"safe"` mode is what PyYAML, from which ruamel.yaml was
orginally derived, gives by default, the "leaf collections" are in flow-style.
That is more compact, than the all-block-style output of the default (`typ="rt"`),
which doesn't always increase readability. Especially in low numbers of total items (so the total fits in a window),
or when the leaf collections have many items (and they wrap over multiple lines).

So the reason why round-trip defaults to all-block-style is because I agree that it looks
nicer. Of course when round-trip is used for its intended purpose, the
original style of each collection is preserved.

The difference is caused by the `default_flow_style` attribute on the `YAML()` instance set to `None` for `"safe"` mode and
to `False` for `"rt"` mode:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {'data': {'interval': 5, 'compression': '3'}, 'player': {'ffmpeg': {'name': 'me'}}}


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ="safe")
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
data:
  compression: '3'
  interval: 5
player:
  ffmpeg:
    name: me
```

If you set the attribute to `True` you'll get output that is completely flow-style.